# How to remove one Windows partition to install Ubuntu, but keep other partitions on drive?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I'm using Windows 10 currently and would like to switch it just to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS thus removing windows 10 completely. However, I'd like to keep the data stored in other partitions. I have One Hard Drive With 2 partitions on it, namely C and D at the moment with Windows 10 installed on C:.. I would like to retain the data from the other partition in Ubuntu. Can anyone please tell me what steps I need to take in order to achieve this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Mucking about with partitions and installing a new operating system are both inherently risky tasks. A backup of your data before you begin is wise.

Comment: Installing an OS on a partition generally deletes all data on that partition.  Depending on size and amount of data, you might be able to shrink D partition with it's data from Windows and make a new partition for Ubuntu.

Comment: I recommend keeping Windows 10, and setting up your system as a dual-boot with Windows and Ubuntu. Keep Windows 10 for doing BIOS updates, and running Windows-only app for which there may be no Ubuntu equivalent. Boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and show me a screenshot of `gparted`. What you ask is really not difficult.

Answer (score 0):

During the setup process, when you are at the [Allocate drive space](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#6-allocate-drive-space) step, select `something else`. There you can delete/format partitions as you will. For more details on manual partitioning, check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) question.